# How to replace in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
try {
    // Use '' al default
    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        unset($_GET['url']);
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
    $proxy = new Proxy();
    echo $proxy->run($url, $_GET, $_POST);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

This is the part of the code I'm having issues with specifically:

```
echo $proxy->run($url, $_GET, $_POST);
```

This will echo a website after running it through a proxy.  What I'm trying to do is replace `<head>` with the following text: `<head> this is a test`

So, I tried changing to code to this:

```
try {
    // Use '' al default
    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        unset($_GET['url']);
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
    $proxy = new Proxy();
    $proxy_replace = str_replace('<head>','<head> this is a test',$proxy);
    echo $proxy_replace->run($url, $_GET, $_POST);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

But this is the error I'm getting:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class Proxy could not be converted to string in /home/username/public_html/testfolder/index.php on line 249
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: In which variable is the string stored where you want to replace `<head>`? ($url or what?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the replacement on the downloaded HTML, not on the `Proxy` instance. Something like this should work:

```
try {
    // Use '' al default
    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        unset($_GET['url']);
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
    $proxy = new Proxy();
    $html = $proxy->run($url, $_GET, $_POST);
    $html_replace = str_replace('<head>','<head> this is a test',$html);
    echo $html_replace;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```